# update multiple objects in state with single function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 3 different Accordions that a single state controls their open and close state like so:

```
 const [accordionOpen, setAccordionOpen] = useState({
    countryOfOriginAccordion: true,
    schoolAccordion: false,
    areaOfStudyAccordion: false,
  });
```

ideally, I am setting each state with their own function like this:

```
setAccordionOpen((previousState) => ({
                ...previousState,
                schoolAccordion: !accordionOpen.schoolAccordion,
              }))
```

I want to use a single function that changes this value in state dynamically:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const toggleAccordionOpen = (accordionName) => setAccordionOpen((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  [accordionName]: !prevState[accordionName],
}));

// Example of usage
toggleAccordionOpen('countryOfOriginAccordion');
```

If you are using Typescript you can annotate the `accordionName` to a type union:

```
const ACCORDION_NAMES = {
  COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN: 'countryOfOriginAccordion',
  SCHOOL: 'schoolAccordion',
  AREA_OF_STUDY: 'areaOfStudyAccordion',
} as const;

type AccordionNameGeneric<T> = T[keyof T];
type AccordionName = AccordionNameGeneric<typeof ACCORDION_NAMES>;

const toggleAccordionOpen = (accordionName: AccordionName) => 
...
```

And then call it like this:

```
toggleAccordionOpen(ACCORDION_NAMES.COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN);
```